# Running NUnit-Console on a Mac

Tags: macos, jenkins, nunit, nunit-console

Apologies for the nubbery, but I'm having a real pain getting NUnit to run on my Mac.  The overall goal is to have Jenkins on our Mac build server build our Xamarin project and run the relevant tests to the .sln file.

I've got NUnit-Console installed and invoking correctly on the mac. However, whenever I pass it /relative/path/to/solution.sln (or .csproj, we don't have a .nunit or built .dll), NUnit finds the the .sln file correctly, however it then throws this error: Could not find file "/relative/path/to/solution\TestProject.csproj".

The .csproj is there, but NUnit seems to want to append a backslash instead of a forward slash.  Is there some config option I've missed for this?

Comment: I had some issues with getting NUnit.ConsoleRunner running on macOS. Feel free to check out my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29957967/system-componentmodel-win32exception-when-executing-f-nunit-unit-test-code-with/56643238#56643238 that is up-to-date for running it on macOS in 2019 (in the context of F# but the principles should be transferrable to C# projects). I have not encountered any path separator character problems and those may have been resolved through updates.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it doesn't look like you can configure NUnit-Console to not do this. If anyone reads this and is looking for a work around, you just need to get your built files from their location, onto a location that Nunit-console running on windows can access.

For my particular use case with Jenkins as the build manager, I've set the project to build on our MAC server, then as a post build action added 'Archive for Clone Workspace SCM'.  I've then setup another project called [ProjectName]Tests, which has the other project targeted in 'Source Code Management' > 'Clone Workspace'.

The test project then has my relevant calls to nunit-console as a Windows batch script and everything works as expected!

Hope this helps save others some time if they hit the same issue!